# SVG.js how to include the filter module plugin and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have gone to the filter plugin page for svg.js and as usual did not get a clear explanation of how to include it in an html page. But instead get very vague and incomplete instructions. The link is : [svg filter plugin](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.filter.js)

Below is my attempt at including the plugin and making a java script reference to it ...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG.js</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #drawing{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.filter.js/2.0.0/svg.filter.min.js" integrity="sha512-h+93xXE2y1xoTdxikOq871JKTEafksZwzmv7vSMX0ENHGV4zSzqexEEy3mob7/Anp2gaaPFfnVkK9Psdl5PSaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">
        <div id="drawing"></div>
        <script>
            function onload() {
                var draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(800, 800);
                var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: '#f06', x:50, y:50});
                rect.filter(function(add) {
                  add.gaussianBlur('15')
                });       
                var image = draw.image('bear.jpg').size(300, 300);
                for (var i in image) {
                    console.log(i);
                }
                image.filterWith(function (add) {
                    add.gaussianBlur(30)
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get back an error in the browser console stating ...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at svg.filter.js:1:1)
svg-filters.html:20 Uncaught TypeError: rect.filter is not a function
    at onload (svg-filters.html:20:22)
    at onload (svg-filters.html:14:30)
```

The instructions merely state ...

```
Npm
npm i @svgdotjs/svg.filter.js
Yarn
yarn add @svgdotjs/svg.filter.js

Include this plugin after including the svg.js library in your html document.
```

My question has 2 parts :

1. Where does Npm and Yarn fit into the picture to get the code running and how do i make the code work ?
2. What is the cdn link for svg.filter.js like 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net' ?

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help out.

As per Nick Friesen i included the correct js include but now get the following error in the console ...

```
Dom.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeName')
    at Element.Dom (Dom.js:22:22)
    at new Element (Element.js:19:22)
    at Function.invent (adopter.js:153:29)
    at svg.filter.min.js:4:2801
    at svg.filter.min.js:4:8878
Dom @ Dom.js:22
Element @ Element.js:19
invent @ adopter.js:153
(anonymous) @ svg.filter.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ svg.filter.min.js:4
svg-filters.html:27 Uncaught TypeError: image.filterWith is not a function
    at onload (svg-filters.html:27:23)
    at onload (svg-filters.html:14:30)
```

Comment: A helpful link you may want to check out is here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/svg.filter.js/2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

1. NPM and Yarn are package managers which assist in managing different
   dependencies. By using these tools, you're able to handle anything
   your project relies on to function.
2. The CDN URl is below: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.filter.js/2.0.0/svg.filter.min.js
   Something you might be interested in as well is the script tag:

   ```
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.filter.js/2.0.0/svg.filter.min.js" integrity="sha512-h+93xXE2y1xoTdxikOq871JKTEafksZwzmv7vSMX0ENHGV4zSzqexEEy3mob7/Anp2gaaPFfnVkK9Psdl5PSaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
   ```

Comment: I added the changes that Nick Friesen advised but there are still errors coming up. Thanks Nick, much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if this is going to be answered. Fuzzyma, could you maybe offer assistance here? The instructions on the svg.js filer pugin doc does not give enough detail to someone that is not skilled in advanced javasript concepts. Hope you are listening for SVG.JS questions.

Comment: @starrezzy, I would suggest to try using the instructions within the document, and to do so, you'll need to change the environment you most likely are work within to develop. After looking further at the CDN I provided, I'm not certain it's the same plugin. Here's a video which may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjyLXmw_mSU